# Installing animation-nodes addon on blender 2.81

Tags: animation-nodes, error

I've been trying to install and activate animation-nodes... to no avail.
Thus far its the only addon I've run into so much trouble with.

I've tried uninstalling blender 2.81, deleting any remnant files, then reinstalling blender, but it keeps giving me errors.

This is the current log message I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\2.81\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.81\scripts\addons\animation_nodes\__init__.py", line 166, in <module>
    auto_load.init()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.81\scripts\addons\animation_nodes\auto_load.py", line 23, in init
    modules = get_all_submodules(Path(__file__).parent)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.81\scripts\addons\animation_nodes\auto_load.py", line 51, in get_all_submodules
    return list(iter_submodules(directory, directory.name))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.81\scripts\addons\animation_nodes\auto_load.py", line 55, in iter_submodules
    yield importlib.import_module("." + name, package_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\2.81\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.81\scripts\addons\animation_nodes\libs\FastNoiseSIMD\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . node_base import Noise3DNodeBase
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.81\scripts\addons\animation_nodes\libs\FastNoiseSIMD\node_base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . wrapper import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm not sure what I should to do to properly activate it.
Any help would be most appreciated since I really want to learn to use this addon.

Comment: Did you install it via .zip file or did you unpack it manually?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? I am having the same problem

Comment: installing vc_redist.x64 from did the trick

[link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) _italic_ **bold** `code`